# DHCPSAPI DhcpAddServer linker error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, lnk2001

I'm trying to use the [DHCP Server Management API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363376(v=vs.85).aspx) in a c++ application. When I want to use the DhcpAddServer function I always get a linker error (LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _DhcpAddServer). All other functions seem to work fine.

I already tried SDK V7.0A and V7.1 (the target system is Win XP).

Here is a test code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <dhcpsapi.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "dhcpsapi.lib")

DWORD TestDHCPAddServer();
DWORD TestDHCPGetVersion();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}

DWORD TestDHCPAddServer()
{
    DHCP_SERVER_INFO serverInfo;
    DWORD errorCode=0;

    serverInfo.Version = 0;
    serverInfo.ServerName = L"xxxx";
    serverInfo.ServerAddress = 1234;
    serverInfo.Flags = 0;
    serverInfo.State = 0;
    serverInfo.DsLocation = NULL;
    serverInfo.DsLocType = 0;

    errorCode = DhcpAddServer(0, NULL, &serverInfo, NULL, NULL);

  return errorCode;
}

DWORD TestDHCPGetVersion() 
{
    DWORD majorVersion = 0;
    DWORD minorVersion = 0;
    DWORD errorCode = 0;

    errorCode = DhcpGetVersion(NULL, &majorVersion, &minorVersion);

  return errorCode;
}
```

When the TestDHCPAddServer is removed, the code compiles, which means, that the lib works in general.
I also used dumpbin.exe /exports and it says that the function should be available in both versions of the lib.

When running the linker with /verbose I can see that it finds DhcpGetVersion in the lib, but not DhcpAddServer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to compile the code using the compiler option /Gz (using calling convention _stdcall as default instead of _cdecl).
In the given header file of dhcpsapi.h of the platform SDK, for some functions (including DhcpAddServer) there is no explicitly given calling convention. This means, the default compiler option is used (_cdecl). But standard for Win32 Api is _stdcall.